# Who among the registered users visited that page?

Tags: user-registration, statistics

I have a site on which users register so as to view xy protected posts accessible only to those who log in.

The customer wants to know who among these registered users (name, surname, email...) has seen this or that protected post.
Thank you!

Comment: This is a question for Simple Membership's support team. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: Thanks Pat.
The reference to Simple Membership was only to complete the request, I have now deleted it, that is not the heart of my question

Comment: You would either have to record user IDs to the `post_meta` or a custom table, or you'd have to record post IDs (not recommended) to `user_meta` so that you can run a report.  I'd go with a custom table that records `id` (auto-incremented), `post_id`, `viewer_ids` (a serialized array of user IDs).
Then you can just run a custom DB query to pull results - even show it in the protected post's back end.

Comment: Thanks Tony,
Your solution seems perfect to me but I don't have enough skills to implement it.
In the meantime, I found a plugin that's right for me, WP Activity Log. That's enough for now.
Thanks again, have a nice day